# How do I completely close a file if an exception is caught in a using block?

Tags: c#, filestream, using

I have an application that needs to parse a file, using FileStream. If that file is used by another process, the FileStream initialization throws an IOException. I catch that exception, telling the user to close the file, and I offer to let the user "Retry." Unfortunately, every Retry results in another IOException being thrown, even if the user closed the file. Why is this happening, and how can it be fixed?

I have the FileStream in a using block, and I open the file with FileShare.Read. Since it is inside the using block, it should get disposed when the exception is thrown, shouldn't it?

```
// Read all the lines in the file and save them to a List
try
{
    using(FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[RECORD_LENGTH];
            count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, RECORD_LENGTH);
            fileLines.Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
        } while(fileStream.CanRead && count > 0);
    }
}
catch(IOException)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("There was a problem reading the file:\n" + path +
        "\nPlease ensure it is not used by another process and try again.", "File Error",
        MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    if(result == DialogResult.Retry)
        ParseFile(path);
    else
        return null;
}
```

Things I have tried:

- Calling the method recursively (as seen above)
- Putting a label before the try block, with `goto` in place of the recursive method call
- Adding a `retryFlag`, setting it in the catch block, then recalling `ParseFile(path)` **after** the catch block if the flag is on

Each of these solutions ended in the same result: a never-ending cycle of IOExceptions being thrown.

Comment: Please, don't use goto! Encapsulate the file logic in a method, and call It again when the user say Retry.

Comment: @ColinM Thanks for the insight. How do you suppose I add my Retry logic, then?

Comment: I think you need to read up on proper Exception handling. Here are two articles on the mater I link often: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET | IOExpcetions are specifically "Exogenous" exceptions. The thing is, those can be both User Fixable (plug the USB Stick back in) and non-user Fixable (lack of Rights). So no mater how often you tried, you still have to expect them. And you can not do more then ask the user waht to do.

Comment: I'd do the retry one level above, in the calling method

Comment: @Fals I've edited the code snippet with the recursive method call, as opposed to the goto, though I left the goto in 'things I've tried.'

Comment: @Christopher Thanks. I admit I am pretty new to exception handling. I'll give those a read.

Comment: @ColinM I don't know why I hadn't thought of that. That might work, thanks.

Comment: Recursion could lead to a `StackOverflowException` if there is an issue, as Christopher's comment suggests, that hasn't been fixed, and if `IOException` keeps getting thrown.

Comment: Did you inspect the subsequent `IOException` to see what the error message is? Perhaps the file being in use wasn't the only problem.

Comment: Also, if all you are doing is trying to read into an `IEnumerable<string>` why not just use `File.ReadAllLines()`?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, everyone. I was able to rewrite my code to not even need this. The file I want to read was first FTPed from a mainframe, but since FtpWebResponse reads in the bytes already, I just save the bytes directly from there instead of writing them to a file then reading from that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to directly answer the question asked:

You don't need to, the using block will close the stream.  Behind the scenes using blocks utilize a try-catch-finally and in the finally block they call dispose which will close your stream.

Many of the comments make other good points, but I hope this answers your question.

Something else you may want to try is simply outputting the exception.message instead of overwriting with your own to close file.  The IOException your getting might not be that one...